# Laravel Socialite facebook login: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: laravel, facebook-authentication, laravel-socialite

I know this question has asked before many times. I've tried every one but no luck,

I my situation,

Website url: `https://mywebsite.com/qa`

redirect url: `https://mywebsite.com/qa/login/facebook/callback`

I have added my domain to app domain, redirect url to valid oAuth redirect url. But same error.

I even created a new app.

However facebook authentication is working fine with `https://mywebsite.com/` domain. It's is a different app and a website.

The issue happens only with the site in the sub folder.

Any help ?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6RRm.png)

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of your error ?

Comment: @AbhinavVerma I've attached the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if "***Valid OAuth Redirect URIs***" in Facebook app "***Facebook login***" setting is properly defined like shown in screenshot attached ?

Also have you checked if your app has [strict mode](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/#strict_mode) enabled ?

This error occurs if your OAuth setting is not correct.

[image]

I would suggest to check all settings of your app thoroughly.

Comment: Thank for your response. Just checked the redirect urls it's all good. :-(

Comment: And what about OAuth settings ?

Comment: Also checked. It's all good. I even verified the redirect urls.

Comment: That's quite weird, can you then check storage/log/laravel.log file ? and see what all errors are there ?

Comment: I found the issue. It was my mistake. I used a wrong `client_id`.

Comment: Thank your for the help